# How does slurm determine memory usage of jobs

Tags: slurm

Recently a user was running an interactive job on our cluster.  We use slurm as the workload manager.  He got his allocation via :

```
 salloc --cpus-per-task=48 --time=14-0 --partition=himem
```

This requests an entire high memory (1.5TB) machine on our cluster.  He ran his job.  While it was running, on his screen he got the error message (or something like this):

```
salloc: Error memory limit exceeded
```

I logged into the node and, using `top`, his job was only taking 310GB in RES.  However within the slurmd.log there is a slew of errors (spanning 8 hours!) like this:

```
[2017-08-03T23:21:55.200] [398692.4294967295] Step 398692.4294967295 exceeded memory limit (1588997632 > 1587511296), being killed
```

QUESTION: Why does top think that he's using 310GB while slurm thinks he is using 1.58TB?

Comment: since slurm reportedly killed a process, It could be the case that at some point in time there indeed was a process spawned by the user that used 1.5TB, however when you logged in it was already gone. If you happen to have a RedHat or derivative system you might have [sadc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Introduction_To_System_Administration/s3-resource-tools-sar-sadc.html) running and collecting mem usage data in 10 minutes interval to check this hypothesis.

Comment: I don't think that is the case, the pid reported in the above `Step 398692.` matches the pid of the 310GB process.  I was watching `top` and the slurm log while it was generating all the `Step 398692.4294967295 exceeded memory limit` errors.  While it was generating those errors, there simply wasn't any process that had that much memory.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, Slurm uses `/proc/<pid>/stat` to get the memory values. In your case, you were not able to witness the incriminated process probably as it was killed by Slurm, as suggested by @Dmitri Chubarov.

Another possibility is that you have met a Slurm bug which was corrected just recently in version 17.2.7. From the change log:

> -- Increase buffer to handle long /proc//stat output so that Slurm can    read correct RSS value and take action on jobs using more
>   memory    than    requested.

The fact that Slurm repeatedly tried to kill the process (you mentioned several occurrences of the entry in the logs) indicates that the machine was running low on RAM and the `slurmd` was facing issues while trying to kill the process. I suggest you activate `cgroups` for task control ; it is much more robust.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out this change.  The associated bug with this change is : https://bugs.schedmd.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3999  .  We are currently using the cgroups plugin for slurm.  In the bug fix they changed the length of the buffer from 256->512 bytes.  I'm going to see if I can replicate the errors and check the length of /proc/<pid>/stat.  The issue that I'm having is a bit different than the issue described in the bug, but it is definitely worth a try.